# Spark Standalone Mode: Connection to 127.0.1.1:<PORT> refused

Tags: scala, mapreduce, apache-spark

I'm using Spark 0.7.2 in standalone mode with the following driver program to process ~90GB (compressed: 19GB) of logdata using 7 workers and 1 distinct master:

```
System.setProperty("spark.default.parallelism", "32")
val sc = new SparkContext("spark://10.111.1.30:7077", "MRTest", System.getenv("SPARK_HOME"), Seq(System.getenv("NM_JAR_PATH")))
val logData = sc.textFile("hdfs://10.111.1.30:54310/logs/")
val dcxMap = logData.map(line => (line.split("\\|")(0),   
                                  line.split("\\|")(9)))
                                  .reduceByKey(_ + " || " + _)
dcxMap.saveAsTextFile("hdfs://10.111.1.30:54310/out")
```

After all the `ShuffleMapTasks` of stage 1 are completed:

```
Stage 1 (reduceByKey at DcxMap.scala:31) finished in 111.312 s
```

it submits stage 0:

```
Submitting Stage 0 (MappedRDD[6] at saveAsTextFile at DcxMap.scala:38), which is now runnable
```

After some serialization it prints

```
spark.MapOutputTrackerActor - Asked to send map output locations for shuffle 0 to host23
spark.MapOutputTracker - Size of output statuses for shuffle 0 is 2008 bytes
spark.MapOutputTrackerActor - Asked to send map output locations for shuffle 0 to host21
spark.MapOutputTrackerActor - Asked to send map output locations for shuffle 0 to host22
spark.MapOutputTrackerActor - Asked to send map output locations for shuffle 0 to host26
spark.MapOutputTrackerActor - Asked to send map output locations for shuffle 0 to host24
spark.MapOutputTrackerActor - Asked to send map output locations for shuffle 0 to host27
spark.MapOutputTrackerActor - Asked to send map output locations for shuffle 0 to host28
```

After this, nothing happens anymore, also `top` suggests that the workers are now all idle.
If I look at the logs at the worker machines, at each of them the same thing happens:

```
13/06/21 07:32:25 INFO network.SendingConnection: Initiating connection to [host27/127.0.1.1:34288]
13/06/21 07:32:25 INFO network.SendingConnection: Initiating connection to [host27/127.0.1.1:36040] 
13/06/21 07:32:25 INFO network.SendingConnection: Initiating connection to [host27/127.0.1.1:50467]
13/06/21 07:32:25 INFO network.SendingConnection: Initiating connection to [host27/127.0.1.1:60833]
13/06/21 07:32:25 INFO network.SendingConnection: Initiating connection to [host27/127.0.1.1:49893]
13/06/21 07:32:25 INFO network.SendingConnection: Initiating connection to [host27/127.0.1.1:39907]
```

Then, for **each** of these "initiating connection" attempts, it throws the same error at each of the workers (showing the logs for host27 as an example and only the first occurence of the error):

```
13/06/21 07:32:25 WARN network.SendingConnection: Error finishing connection to host27/127.0.1.1:49893
java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused
    at sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.checkConnect(Native Method)
    at sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.finishConnect(SocketChannelImpl.java:701)
    at spark.network.SendingConnection.finishConnect(Connection.scala:221)
    at spark.network.ConnectionManager.spark$network$ConnectionManager$$run(ConnectionManager.scala:127)
    at spark.network.ConnectionManager$$anon$4.run(ConnectionManager.scala:70)
```

Why does this happen? It seems like the workers can communicate fine with each other, the only problem seems to occur when they want to send a message to themselves; in the above example, host27 tries to send 6 messages to itself, but fails 6 times. Sending messages to other workers works fine.
Does someone have an idea?

**edit**: perhaps it has to do with spark using 127.0.**1**.1 instead of 127.0.**0**.1?
`/etc/hosts` looks like the following:

```
127.0.0.1       localhost
127.0.1.1       host27.<ourdomain>  host27
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out that the problem is related to [this](https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!topic/spark-users/oJAsgVc8Www) problem.
However, for me setting SPARK_LOCAL_IP on the workers didn't fix the problem.
I had to change `/etc/hosts` to:

```
127.0.0.1       localhost
```

and now it runs smoothly.